# Append a div with dynamic text to another div without losing the data - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, append

I have a question that might seems easy but I can't seem to find a solution.

```
<div class="text">
  <p class="paragraph">
    <span>The main text is this one </span>
    <span class="bold">with bold text near</span>
  </p>
    <p class="bold-dynamic" style="" data-message-code="dynamic-message">Add me near the other paragraph without losing the dynamic content</p>
</div>
```

So basically, I have to unite all these paragraphs + spans together on one line without losing the dynamic content I am getting in the 3rd paragraph.

The final message should look like: "The main text is this one with bold text near, add me near the other paragraph without losing the dynamic content."

How can I achive this? I can't use innerText/innerHTML, appendchild and I can't harcode the paragraph with the dynamic content. Many thanks.

Comment: why cant you use innerText/innerHTML or appendChild? Can you give an example of the markup for your desired result too

Answer (score 0):

Without `innerText`, `innerHTML` and DOM manipulation functions there is not really any way to change the document?

I am assuming that you can use them, but that you've not managed to make it work?

Please add more detail to your question if this is not the case.

<s>Without knowing what your desired markup is, I've just removed all the `p.paragraph` and replaced them with a textNode with their innerText. Also setting the `display: inline` to `p.bold-dynamic` to remove the new line(s)</s>

I've updated the code to now just insert lots of `display: inline`

```js
// find all p.paragrah inside div.text
document.querySelectorAll("div.text > p.paragraph").forEach((element) => {
  // insert a textNode with the innerText of the p.paragraph
  //element.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(element.innerText), element)
  // set p.bold-dynamic display: inline
  //element.parentNode.querySelector("p.bold-dynamic").setAttribute("style", "display: inline;")
  // remove the p.paragraph
  //element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
  
  element.setAttribute("style", "display: inline;")
  element.querySelectorAll("*").forEach((tag) => {
    tag.setAttribute("style", "display: inline;")
  })
  element.parentNode.querySelector("p.bold-dynamic").setAttribute("style", "display: inline;")
})
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p class="paragraph">
    <span>The main text is this one </span>
    <span class="bold">with bold text near</span>
  </p>
  <p class="bold-dynamic" style="" data-message-code="dynamic-message">Add me near the other paragraph without losing the dynamic content</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p class="paragraph">
    <span>The main text is this one </span>
    <span class="bold">with bold text near</span>
  </p>
  <p class="bold-dynamic" style="" data-message-code="dynamic-message">Add me near the other paragraph without losing the dynamic content</p>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <p class="paragraph">
    <span>The main text is this one </span>
    <span class="bold">with bold text near</span>
  </p>
  <p class="bold-dynamic" style="" data-message-code="dynamic-message">Add me near the other paragraph without losing the dynamic content</p>
</div>
```